# How to dynamically create an instance of a class and a method?

Tags: c#

I've made the following class

```
    class Country
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Population { get; set; }

        public Country (string name, int population)
        {
            Name = name;
            Population = population;

        }

        public string GetCountryInfo()
        {
            return "Country" + Name + " has the population of: " + Population + ".";
        }
    }
```

I would like to dynamically create an instance of this class and call the method (yet again dynamically). How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define dynamic? Why can you not call `new Country`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use reflection.  Imagine you implemented ICountry as follows:

```
interface ICountry
{
    string GetCountryInfo();
}
```

And you created another Country object type as:

```
class CountryB : ICountry
{
    public CountryB(string name, int population)
    {
    }
    public string GetCountryInfo()
    {
        return "This is countryB";
    }
}
```

You could use reflection to get a reference to the constructor for both (including the original Country) of these objects and invoke it.  Invoking it will give you a new instance of that object.

Assuming that you're in a console application, the following would work; you can tweak this as needed:

```
var countryTypes = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetTypes()
  .Where(t => t.GetInterface("ICountry") != null).ToList();
countryTypes.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Name));
var countries = countryTypes
  .Select(t => t.GetConstructor(new[]{typeof(string), typeof(int)}))
  .Select(t => t.Invoke(new Object []{ "help me", 911}) as dynamic)
  .ToList();
  countries.ForEach(t=> Console.WriteLine(t.GetCountryInfo()));
```

You can see a working version in this dotnet fiddle: 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/DGYJBM

-Isaac

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am correctly getting your req.

What you can do is extract an interface `ICountry`. Have `Country` implement `ICountry`.

Then, declare a variable of type `ICountry`.

Now,

```
ICountry country;
country c = new Country(“My Imaginary Country”, 1000000);
```

---

What’s dynamic here?

This interface can be implemented by many other classes. However, you can declare a single variable and depending upon the situation, call different class’ constructor.